# How to convert list elements to string array

Tags: javascript

```
var categoryList="[Service,Ticket,Bill,Entertainment,Restaurant]";
```

I want to convert the above String as String array like below:-

```
var categoryList=["Service","Ticket","Bill","Entertainment","Restaurant"];
```

Any Solution is appreciable.

Comment: `categoryList.substring(1, categoryList.length - 1).split(',')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var yourString = "[Service,Ticket,Bill,Entertainment,Restaurant]"

var categoryList = yourString.substring(1, yourString.length-1).split(",") // removing [] and splitting with `,`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
categoryList = categoryList.replace(/\[|\]/g,"").split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)** and **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**

```js
var categoryList = "[Service,Ticket,Bill,Entertainment,Restaurant]"
  .slice(1, -1) // get `[` and `]`removed string
  .split(','); // split based on comma to get array

console.log(
  categoryList
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another short solution using `String.match` function:

```
var categoryList="[Service,Ticket,Bill,Entertainment,Restaurant]";
console.log(categoryList.match(/\w+\b/g));  // ["Service", "Ticket", "Bill", "Entertainment", "Restaurant"]
```